# What is the difference between plug-in-type methods and methods in a global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

**In terms of efficiency,**

what's the fastest and most standard way to tweak a function in javascript?

Plugin-style coding would be like this.

```
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {

var pluginName = "SoketManager",
    dataPlugin = "plugin_" + pluginName,
    settings = {
        target: this,
        width: 350,
        height: 150,
        theme: 'default'
    }

var Plugin = {
    // instance...
}    

Plugin.prototype = {
    connect: function() {
         //something.
    },
    disconnect: function() {
         //something.
    },
    sendmessage: function() {
         //something...
    },
    etc: function() {

    }
  //etc2: function() .......
}

$.fn[pluginName] = function (arg, contents) {
var args, instance;
if (typeof arg === 'string' && typeof instance[arg] === 'function') {
            args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
            return instance[arg].apply(instance, args); 
}
```

And using global variable would be like this..

```
var SocketManager = {
    sock: '',
    connect: function () {
        var stdInfo = new JSONClientParameters();
        var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.39:3000', {
            query: stdInfo.toGetString()
            //'reconnect': true,
            // 'reconnection delay': 500,//default 500
            //'max reconnection attempts': 10
        });
        kdbSocketManager.ksock = socket;
        socket.on('connect', function () {
            alert('successfully connected to the database!!');
        });
    },
    disconnect: function () {
        this.ksock.disconnect();
    },
    sendMessage: function (pMsg, pTargetId) {
        this.ksock.emit('sendMessage', { msg: pMsg, targetId: pTargetId });
    },
```

I see no point in coding like the plugin-way. Is it much more simple and easy to read to code like the latter one? could somebody explain this in detail?

Comment: may be you should read about `closure`.

Comment: jQuery plugins allow you to share the same global object, and enforce a standard structure. Really though, your second code example doesn't have any DOM manipulation code - why would it need to be a jQuery plugin in the first place?

Comment: This is just an example code. forget about the inside codes. please look at the code style instead. I can call the connect method by typing SocketManager.connect() and $.selector.SocketManager('connect'). as I see, the former one is much more simpler... but There's gotta be a reason for doing like that. That's what I'm curious about.

Comment: The plugin style is useful when you are manipulating DOM elements. It also affords you a consistent api that you can extend from, instead of rolling your own. In your example, it wouldn't matter I don't think, but if you were writing something that worked on a (set of) DOM elements and did some magic, then it would be advisable to use jquery as your api, as it already has support for most things DOM related.